# Unable to Run my Filter implemented with ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: java, jersey, jax-ws, jax-rs

I am trying to parse the GET  response through a common filter and send response to the client according the content received. But I am not able to execute the Filter class. I've added the code snippet below. Any help would be appreciated

```
@FrontierResponse
@Provider
public class PoweredbyResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

    if (requestContext.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
        System.out.println("hellos");
    }

    //responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
}
```

}

My custom Annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NameBinding
public @interface FrontierResponse {
}
```

and this is my resource class

```
@GET
@FrontierResponse
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<String> list() {...}
```

for additional information i am using

jersey jersey-bundle-1.17.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate *the method* of the resource class by `@FrontierResponse`, not the resource class. Or you may annotate extension of `Application` class if you want to use your filter for all requests. [Check spec for more details.](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html)

EDIT:
`@NameBinding` is in JAX-RS since v2.0. You need to use implementation o that specification, that is Jersey 2.x. In the jersey 1.x this annotation will be ignored.

Comment: Actually  that is a annotation for "the method" of a resource class not in the Resource class but  still the filter class is not being executed.

Comment: Is this possible to do with the version of jersey i am using. jersey 1.17 and javax.ws.rs-api-2.0,jar? Will there be any library version conflict?

Comment: Sorry, I've seen what I want to see, not what was written.